# Xamarin Forms Binding. How to display 1 of 3 different strings based on some conditions

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, binding

I am a little confused as to how best to display 1 of 3 different strings based on a condition. I have 2 data fields - mobile number and telephone number and I want to display them in a listview. If there is a mobile number I want it to display that otherwise if there is no mobile number but a telephone number I want to display the telephone number. Or if there is neither a mobile number or telephone number then I want to display the string "No number available".

< Label Text="{Binding NumberText}" TextColor="Teal" FontSize="11"/>

Comment: That logic should be done in the ViewModel. And only one `String` will be used to be bounded to the label, the content of that string you can change in the ViewModel/Code behind

Comment: Another way would be to bind the whole model and write a converter that takes the model, gets the properties and does the check.

Answer (score 3):

Use a public property that returns the desired string based on your conditions (consider using a ViewModel)

```
public string NumberText
{
    get
    {
        if (this.hasMobileNumber)
        {
            return this.mobileNumber;
        }

        if (this.hasPhoneNumber)
        {
            return this.phoneNumber;
        }

        return "No number available";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set this in your model

```
//Assuming phoneNumber and mobileNumber are declared in your model
[JsonIgnore]
    public string NumberText
    {
        get
        {
            string number = "";
            if (phoneNumber != null || phoneNumber != "")
            {
                number = phoneNumber;
            }

            else if (mobileNumber != null || mobileNumber != "")
            {
                number = mobileNumber;
            }

            else
            {
                number = "No number available";
            }
            return number;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(...)`